# Check '!= null" not working

Tags: java, string, exception, nullpointerexception, operators

I have facing  `"NullPointerException"` in code. We have already check not null, but it's not working for us in the below screenshot. I already check `folderInfoData.getSelectedInfoRole() != null` but its enter to the if statement. It's `private SelectOption<String> selectedInfoRole;` type.

How to fixed this issue?

```
18:26:22,589 246302 ERROR [zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl                           ] - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.web.viewmodel.FolderProcessInfoViewModel.saveInfoDetails(FolderProcessInfoViewModel.java:234)
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.web.viewmodel.FolderProcessInfoViewModel.saveProcessInfo(FolderProcessInfoViewModel.java:201)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:113)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doExecute(BinderImpl.java:1748)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doCommand(BinderImpl.java:1509)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.access$1500(BinderImpl.java:108)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent0(BinderImpl.java:1378)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent(BinderImpl.java:1330)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2746)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2717)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2658)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1765)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1550)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1260)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:603)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:485)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:494)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.csdcsystems.servlets.AmandaSessionFilter.doFilter(AmandaSessionFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18:26:22,597 246302  INFO [csdcsystems.amanda.web.AmandaPerformanceMeter     ] - Command name:saveProcessInfo
```

Here is Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How do we suppose to copy paste your image to code?

Comment: Your screenshot of the expression evaluation shows us, that the value returned by the method is not `null`. Instead the `toString` method seems to print `null` which is a difference.

Comment: @ZouZou this line giving nullpointerException

Comment: @user3062776 Do you have any `NullPointerException`? If so post the stacktrace and the corresponding line, because it seems that value is not null.

Comment: Are you sure that `.getFolderProcessInforecord()` cannot return null?

Comment: I suggest you place the parts of expression into local variables until you can see the cause of the problem.  Are you sure equals() is not throwing this NPE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you have a NullPointerException because either `folderInfoData.getFolderprocessInforecord()` or `folderInfoData.getSelectedInfoRole().getValue()` returns null and then you call `getInfoValue` on it.

To help debugging similar issues, try to keep lines simpler:

```
infoRole = folderInfoData.getSelectedoInfoRole().getValue();
infoRecord = folderInfoData.getFolderprocessInforecord().getValue();
if (!infoRole.equals(infoRecord) {
  ...
}
```

This would report a NullPointerException on the second line and would save you some time debugging.

Comment: @lvaylo i check its not working for me validProcessInfoRow.getInfoType() == InfoType.CHOOSE && folderInfoData.getSelectedInfoRole() != null && folderInfoData.getFolderProcessInforecord() != null

Comment: @user3062776 then how about `folderInfoData.getSelectedInfoRole().getValue()` are you sure it is not null?

Comment: folderInfoData.getSelectedInfoRole()  is null

Comment: I guess you mean `folderInfoData.getSelectedInfoRole().getValue()`?